# How to trigger an add button with both a click and enter keyboard button?

Tags: javascript

I am working on making this ToDo app. I can add tasks by clicking on the add button, but I am unable to figure out how to also make it so that tasks can be added using the enter keyboard button.

```
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function on `keydown` event by checking the [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) value:

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if(event.code == "Enter"){
    newElement()
  }
}, true);

function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput"/>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you, i was looking for this exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put the elements within a `<form>` and bind to the *submit* event. Both of clicking on a submit button or hitting `Enter` in a text field will submit the form

```js
// Minified your function for brevity
function newElement(){var e=document.createElement("li"),t=document.getElementById("myInput").value,n=document.createTextNode(t);e.appendChild(n),""===t?alert("You must write something!"):document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(e),document.getElementById("myInput").value="";var d=document.createElement("SPAN"),m=document.createTextNode("×");d.className="close",d.appendChild(m),e.appendChild(d)}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  newElement()
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="myInput">
  <button type="submit">➕</button>
</form>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i wanted the solution within js. But this one worked too. Appreciate it.